# Script to create notes in multiple dropdown lists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been working on a script (kindly supported by @Tanaike) which allows me to have a note appear when I select certain information from a dropdown list in Google Sheets. The script I have used is detailed below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheetNames = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "14", "15", "17", "20", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "31", "33", "35", "37", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "50", "52", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "66/0", "66/1", "66/2", "66/3", "66/4", "66/5", "66/6", "66/7", "66/8", "66/9", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "73", "76", "77", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92",,,];
      if (sheetNames.some(s => range.getSheet().getSheetName() == s) && range.columnStart == 5) {
  const object = {
      AVD: "AV Dawson Middlesbrough",
      BA: "Basford Hall, Crewe (FLR)",
      BH: "Barrow Hill Roundhouse",
      BKR: "Bo'ness & Kinneil Railway",
      BN: "Bounds Green (LNER)",
      CD: "Crewe Diesel (Locomotive Storage Ltd)",
      CE: "Crewe Electric TMD",
      CF: "Cardiff Canton",
      CFT: "Cardiff Tidal",
      ChaR: "Chasewater Railway",
      CPRR: "Chinoor & Princes Risborough Railway",
      CZ: "Central Rivers (Bombardier)",
      DRM: "Doncaster Royal Mail Terminal",
      EH: "Eastleigh (Arriva Traincare)",
      EHY: "Eastleigh East Yard",
      ELY: "Ely Papworth Sidings",
      EML: "EMD Longport",
      FX: "Felixstowe Docks",
      HT: "Heaton, Newcastle",
      IL: "Ilford (Greater Anglia)",
      LA: "Laira (Great Western)",
      LB: "Loughborough Brush Traction",
      LD: "Leeds Midland Road (FLR)",
      LE: "Landore (Great Western)",
      LM: "Long Marston",
      LR: "Leicester L.I.P (UKRL)",
      NA: "Newton Aycliffe (Hitachi)",
      NC: "Norwich Crown Point",
      NM: "Nottingham Eastcroft",                
      PG: "Peterborough (GBRf)",
      PM: "Bristol St Phillips Marsh",
      RR: "Roberts Road, Doncaster",
      SZ: "Southampton Maritime (FLR)",
      TO: "Toton (DBC)",
      TW: "Tonbridge West Yard",                
      TY: "Tyne Yard",
      WB: "Wembley (Alstom)",
      WEN: "Wensleydale Railway",
      WI: "Wishaw",
      ZB: "Doncaster Wabtec",
  };
   const v = range.getValue();
      range.setNote(v in object ? object[v] : "");
    }     

}
```

Basically this script works in all of the sheets that I have named and when I select one of the abbreviations in my dropdown (in `column E`), a note automatically then appears with the full detail ie if I select "AVD" from the dropdown, a note appears stating "AV Dawson Middlesbrough".

This is great and works exactly how I want it to. However, I now wish to expand this to other columns where I use shortened abbreviations in the dropdown and so I also set up the following script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheetNames = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "14", "15", "17", "20", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "31", "33", "35", "37", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "50", "52", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "66/0", "66/1", "66/2", "66/3", "66/4", "66/5", "66/6", "66/7", "66/8", "66/9", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "73", "76", "77", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92",,,];
      if (sheetNames.some(s => range.getSheet().getSheetName() == s) && range.columnStart == 2) {
  const object = {
      ELR: "East Lancashire Railway",
      HST: "Heritage Shunters Trust",

  };
   const v = range.getValue();
      range.setNote(v in object ? object[v] : "");
    }     

}
```

This script is to work in all of the same sheets as the first script but I require this to work in `column B` of the spreadsheet which consists of different data as seen in the above script. Again, as an example, I require this to work so that when I select "HST" from the dropdown, an automatic note appears in that cell stating "Heritage Shunters Trust". Again, I have been able to make this script work as I require it.

However, the problem I now have is that I can't seem to get both scripts working at the same time. So with the new script for `column B` (the 2nd script in my question) working, the script for `column E` is no longer working.

I have suspected that it is something to do with the `range.columnStart` part of the script and so I have tried to add a `range.columnEnd` to the script but had no luck with that and having exhausted any other options I can think of, I have turned back to you guys for some assistance and would be grateful of any received.

Comment: what does `.some` do?

Comment: All functions must have unique names within a project

Comment: Hello @The_Train, are both of the `onEdit` functions in the same project? Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13, yes they were but thanks to Cooper, I have corrected that now so my problem is resolved. Thanks to you both

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to **run both functions in the same script**, you will need to have **different names for both of these functions**.

Therefore, you can try renaming the second function as `onEdit2`.